# How to map different categories as one value?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to group different continents into 5 groups: since Oceania, Antarctica, and Seven seas don't have a significant enough sample size, they should belong to one group

I am trying to include an else statement in the mapping

```
data_mapped = data.copy()
data_mapped['continent'] = data_mapped['continent'].map({'North America':0,'South America':1,'Europe':2,'Africa':3,'Asia':4, else:5})
data_mapped
```

But python doesn't seem to recognize else in this context. Any work around for this problem?

Comment: Is this a `pandas` dataframe?

Comment: yes it is, as a matter of fact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can absolutly do this, although I'm not sure if it's possible quite how you are trying (happy to update if it is possible like that).  I'll set up some test data first:

```
import pandas as pd
continents= ['North America','South America', 'Europe', 
             'Africa', 'Asia', 'Oceania', 'Antarctica', 
             'Oceans', 'Arctic']

df = pd.Series(data=continents)
```

Here is a shortish answer for a Pandas dataframe. I'm setting up a dictionary with the continents that have their own index, and if the continent isn't present in that, then we set the value we've put in for `'None'` in the dictionary:

```
indexed_conts = {'North America':0,'South America':1,
                 'Europe':2,'Africa':3,'Asia':4,'None':5} 

new_df = df.map(lambda x: indexed_conts[x] if x in indexed_conts
              else indexed_conts['None'], continents)
```

Setting up your data this way makes it easier to add more more continents, or extend this to other problem areas much easier than the verbose methods I've put below.

This is a very verbose way of doing this on a simple list.  You can nest your `if`s inside each other:

```
for i in map(lambda x: 0 if x=='North America' 
                  else 1 if x=='South America' 
                  else 2 if x=='Europe' 
                  else 3 if x=='Africa' 
                  else 4 if x=='Asia' 
                  else 5, continents):
    print(i)
```

And you can do use this verbose style on a Pandas dataframe:

```
indexed_df = df.map(lambda x: 0 if x=='North America' 
              else 1 if x=='South America' 
              else 2 if x=='Europe' 
              else 3 if x=='Africa' 
              else 4 if x=='Asia' 
              else 5, continents)
```

Comment: The first pandas dictionary is exactly the syntax I was looking for. thank you!